# Replace 2nd line on downloadstring?

Tags: c#, skype

I have some c# code i have made for an AI

```
 else if (msg.Body.Contains("ai"))

                    {
                        string ai = msg.Body.Replace("!ai ", string.Empty).Replace(" ", "+");
                        WebClient _client = new WebClient();


                        msg.Chat.SendMessage("Getting AI... ");

                        _client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36";



                        //Define what the client is heading to.
                        string a = _client.DownloadString("!Api here!" + ai).Replace("string", "\n");

                        //Display Message
                        msg.Chat.SendMessage(Nick + "AI says: " + a);
                    }
```

But the api gives back 2 lines, and i only need the first line, because that is the only line of use to me, please help!

Comment: Could you show us what the string looks like that you are getting from the api?

Comment: Okay 

"Hi sweety :)string(12) "Hi sweety :)"

Comment: I want to remove everything after "string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the simple `.Remove()` function provided with the string data type like so:

```
int index = a.IndexOf("string");

a = a.Remove(index, a.Length - index);
```

If you wanted to remove everything after the new line then you can replace the `"string"` in the `IndexOf` method with `Environment.NewLine` since `IndexOf` looks for the first instance of the specified parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but i find that the above code is cleaner, once i get it working that is :D

Comment: No problem :). Although using `LINQ` will turn this into a 1-liner. This is an old-school way of doing it imo :P.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
a = a.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).First();
```

Comment: if you want to remove everything after string try:
a.Substring(0,a.IndexOf("string"))

Comment: I'd split on `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: If i upload my code to hastebin, may you fix it for me? i get an error with that bit of code...

Comment: @Nader `First()` is a LINQ method so you must add the `System.Linq` namespace at the top to use it.